# Make text boxes in map window

Tags: labeling, qgis-3

Is there a way in Qgis to create a text box in the map window like you can in the layout window similar to the labelling option in Mapinfo?

I've tried the following:

1. Use text annotations. This isn't optimal because you can't rotate the text annotation and when the window moves doesn't move the annotations.
2. Create a shape file with points and label the points and hide the symbols. This is the best work around but it doesn't seem as easy as creating a text box that you can rotate and assign individual attributes to.

Comment: Please specify which individual attributes you'd like to assign to the text boxes. Because you can easily rotate labels based on feature-attributes (subtab `placement` in the `label`-tab).

Comment: I'm not aware of any text boxes in the Qgis map window. I'm looking for an option like [link](https://support.pitneybowes.com/SearchArticles/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000CtzHCAS&popup=false&lang=en_US) - the labeling tool

Comment: Sorry, should have use paranthesis - "textboxes". You most likely will have to work with labels.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've already figured out the two best ways of putting a text label on the map canvas in QGIS. I found a few plugins that might be useful:

- AnnotationManager: provides a panel to manage annnotations
- Red Layer: allows you to draw quick annotations on the map canvas
- SuperLabeling: Add your label by mouse click only.

There's already an outstanding feature request for [horizontal/vertical text alignment in text annotations](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/18962). If you want 360 degree control over text rotation, you could add a comment to that feature request or make a new request.

Comment: I tried all the plugins - I agree what I came up with is the most efficient way to have labels right now. I'll go over to the link you posted